# Points in KML with custom icon suddenly not displaying in KMLLayer (but Linestrings do)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, google-maps-markers

This code worked perfectly until a short time ago. The KML and the Javascript certainly haven't changed so I'm imagining I have some issue in the KML which a Google update now doesn't like.

I have a Google Maps API implementation which simply loads a KML file into a KMLLayer on a map. Now, I get the Linestrings displaying but not the points.

Here is the relevant snippets from the KML.

```
    <Style id="start">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>0.0</scale>
            <heading>0.0</heading>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://d1b3rm3ifop01h.cloudfront.net/mapicons/start-race-2.png</href>
                <refreshInterval>0.0</refreshInterval>
                <viewRefreshTime>0.0</viewRefreshTime>
                <viewBoundScale>0.0</viewBoundScale>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>

    ...

    <Placemark>
        <name>Baden Powell Horseshoe Bay Trailhead</name>
        <description>Elevation: 54.9 m (180.2 ft)&lt;br /&gt;Very small carpark only accessible travelling north.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.trailhunger.com/junction/820&quot;&gt;Junction Information&lt;/a&gt;</description>
        <styleUrl>#start</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-123.2749314141,49.3669179082,54.93</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the scale element was set to 0.0 and Google very recently changed their Google Maps KML parser to honour the scale element. Setting it to 1.0 made the icons appear.

0.0 is the default for the `de.micromata.opengis.kml` libary I'm using.

The next problem was that the icons were appearing in the wrong position. This was because I needed the hotSpot element to be specified.

This answer was provided by geocodezip@gmail.com on the [Google Maps API issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4226) I raised.

Comment: It would be helpful for others if you showed your final, fixed KML in your answer for comparison.